# how to mock variables inside a function in jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I want to test the 'canViewPage method in jest.
How do mock the const userPages which is the values from the func getUserPage

```
   canViewPage(page){
     const userPages = getUsersPages();
    if(userPages.includes(page)){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
   }


  getUsersPages(){
    // here i hardcode a list of pages, for simplicity purposes
    const pages = ['home','about','contact'];
    return pages

  }
```

here is what i tried

```
test('test canViewPage', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(canViewPage, 'userPages');
    spy.mockReturnValue(['home','about','contact']);

    expect(canViewPage('premiumPage')).toBe(false); 

    spy.mockRestore();
  });
```

I also tried this

```
test('test canViewPage', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(canViewPage, 'getUsersPage');
    spy.mockReturnValue(['home','about','contact']);

    expect(canViewPage('premiumPage')).toBe(false); 

    spy.mockRestore();
  });
```

Comment: You are right to mock `getUsersPage()`, but you setting up the mock/spy incorrectly. `getUsersPages()` is not defined/exported from within `canViewPage()`. Instead try targeting `getUsersPage()` directly to create a mock/spy. With the spy working, then you can assert `canViewPage('premiumPage')` accordingly.

Comment: and how do i do that, thats what i've struggling with

Comment: You may need to share more information regarding the file where `getUsersPage()`, is it can exported function? What have you tried from https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions other than what you shared in your question?

Comment: this question is about mocking return values from a function, not mocking variables

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To mock the value of `userPages` you have to mock `getUserPage`. To achieve this, it depends on where and how `getUserPage` and `canViewPage` are defined. I'm going to assuming these two functions are defined in class `MyAwesomeClass`

```
// MyAwesomeClass.js
export default class MyAwesomeClass {
  canViewPage(page) {
    const userPages = this.getUsersPages();
    if (userPages.includes(page)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }


  getUsersPages() {
    // here i hardcode a list of pages, for simplicity purposes
    const pages = ['home', 'about', 'contact'];
    return pages;
  }
}

// test.js
import MyAwesomeClass from '<path to MyAwesomeClass.js>'
test('test canViewPage', () => {
  const instance = new MyAwesomeClass()
  const spy = jest.spyOn(instance, 'getUsersPages');
  spy.mockReturnValue(['mockItem1','mockItem2','mockItem3']);

  expect(instance.canViewPage('premiumPage')).toBe(false);
  expect(instance.canViewPage('mockItem1')).toBe(true);

  spy.mockRestore();
});
```

if `canViewPage` and `getUsersPages` are static methods within the class, you mock differently

```
test('test canViewPage', () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(MyAwesomeClass, 'getUsersPages');
  spy.mockReturnValue(['mockItem1','mockItem2','mockItem3']);

  expect(MyAwesomeClass.canViewPage('premiumPage')).toBe(false);
  expect(MyAwesomeClass.canViewPage('mockItem3')).toBe(true);

  spy.mockRestore();
});
```

Comment: thats did it for me, the only difference was my case, my functions were stand alone with no class, so imported them like this. 
"import * as MyAwesomeClass from './utils.js' "

Comment: What if there is no class and 'getUsersPages' is just method in that file ?

Comment: @sagar -- have you tried doing import * as MyAwesomeClass from '<filepath>'

Answer (score 0):

This is not Jest but sinon, in case if you can not see the instance of the target class, you can also set mock values as below.
Once specified, mocked values will be returned until `sinon.restore()` called

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const test = await sinon
    .stub(MyAwesomeClass.prototype, 'getUsersPages')
    .returns(['mockItem1','mockItem2','mockItem3']);

const instance = new MyAwesomeClass()
console.log(instance.getUserPages()) // <- this return ['mockItem1','mockItem2','mockItem3']
```

It assume that this is target source code.

```
// MyAwesomeClass.js
export default class MyAwesomeClass {
  canViewPage(page) {
    const userPages = this.getUsersPages();
    if (userPages.includes(page)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
    
  getUsersPages() {
    // here i hardcode a list of pages, for simplicity purposes
    const pages = ['home', 'about', 'contact'];
    return pages;
  }
}

// test.js
import MyAwesomeClass from '<path to MyAwesomeClass.js>'
test('test canViewPage', () => {
  const instance = new MyAwesomeClass()
  const spy = jest.spyOn(instance, 'getUsersPages');
  spy.mockReturnValue(['mockItem1','mockItem2','mockItem3']);

  expect(instance.canViewPage('premiumPage')).toBe(false);
  expect(instance.canViewPage('mockItem1')).toBe(true);

  spy.mockRestore();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Spy and stub is a recommended approach, however in case if you want to access the outside scope object, hack window variable and assign it with desired value

for ex:

```js
var a = 10;
const myfun = () => {
 return a + 20;
}

test('myfun', () => {
  window.a = 20
  expect(myfun).toBe(40)
 }
```

Comment: This is not working as expected with angularjs.

Comment: Not sure what you mean angularJS, do you mean Karma/Jasmine? or JEST

Comment: I think you should avoid using this way making global variables